# Remove Item from Array in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection called Rulesets - each ruleset has an array of "rules". I have the following html which displays each ruleset and each rule:

```
<template name="rulesets">
    {{#each rulesets}}
        {{>rulesetSingle}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="rulesetSingle">
    {{#each rules}}
         <p class="rule-description">{{this}}
             <a href="#" class="rule-delete-btn">x</a>
         </p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to be able to remove the rule when the user clicks the "rule-delete-btn".
I have the following javascript to do this:

```
Template.rulesetSingle.event({
    'click .rule-delete-btn': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var array = Rulesets.rules;
        var index = array.indexOf(this);
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

The delete isn't working because the "array" declaration isn't pulling a valid array. How can I find and store the array that contains "this" which is the current rule that needs to be deleted?

Comment: Do you want to completely remove that array entry form `Rulesets` collection?

Comment: Lets say for example that Rulests.rules is an array containing rule descriptions for 3 rules. I want to be able to delete the selected rule description from the array and have the other 2 still be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `Rulesets.rules` array is an array of objects like :

```
Rulesets : { { title: 'title1', 
               rules : [ {name : 'rule1', description : 'description1'}, 
                         {name : 'rule2', description : 'description2'}
                       ]
             },
             { title: 'title2', 
               rules : [ {name : 'rule1', description : 'description1'}, 
                         {name : 'rule2', description : 'description2'}
                       ]
             } }
```

First, in your `rulesetSingle` template, you must assign the `_id` of that particular document to the `<a>` like :

`<a href="#" name="{{../_id}}"class="rule-delete-btn"> x </a>`

Second thing, you are trying to remove rule entry using `Array.splice()`, this is not possible since the `rules` is a document inside the collection. You must do `update` query as `Rulesets.update()`.

If you have done `allow update` on the server, you can delete this array entry from within the event handler, otherwise you must do `Meteor.call()` by passing `rule` an the `_id` of parent document.

So, the event handler will look something like :

```
 'click .rule-delete-btn': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rule = this;
        var id = e.currentTarget.name;
        Meteor.call('removeRule', id, rule);
  }
```

On the server:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    removeRule: function(id, rule){
      Rulesets.update({_id: id}, {$pull : {rules : rule}});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I actually went about this by creating a collection of Rules and then storing the ruleset ID in the rule collection - then when the delete button is clicked it removes the rule from the collection. But this would have worked too. I had some other reasons for creating a separate collection.

Comment: This is the right answer -- but something which tripped me up badly is that the way I have to call the equivalent of "rule" in my code, it was being converted to a string rather than remaining as an object. Now if I do "JSON.parse(rule)" before calling removeRule, it actually works.