# meteor $pull remove from array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following object in my database:

```
{
    "_id": "fTgR2YtHiZBzzqF6J",
    "following": [
        {
            "user": {
                "_id": "S4dLHRJiuHoyAp26q",
                "fb": {
                    "id": "100006681067911",
                    "name": "Helen Amffhajfgiaa Laubergskymanwitzescusonsteinsen"
                }
            },
            "date": "2013-10-01T17:25:50.305Z"
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "_id": "MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy",
                "fb": {
                    "id": "100006719587007",
                    "name": "Mary Amfgaiehgkg Smithman"
                }
            },
            "date": "2013-10-11T10:47:58.898Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to remove the

```
{
   "user": {
      "_id": "MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy",
      "fb": {
          "id": "100006719587007",
          "name": "Mary Amfgaiehgkg Smithman"
      }
    },
    "date": "2013-10-11T10:47:58.898Z"
}
```

subdocument from the array called "following".

My query to do this looks like this:

```
 Collection.update({"_id":"fTgR2YtHiZBzzqF6J"},
 {
    "$pull": {
        "following": {
             "user": {
                 "_id": "MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy"
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

But nothing happens!

Can someone point me towards my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was: I had to $pull the whole object:

```
 Collection.update({"_id":"fTgR2YtHiZBzzqF6J"},
 {
    "$pull": {
        "following": {
            "user": {
                "_id": "MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy",
                "fb": {
                    "id": "100006719587007",
                    "name": "Mary Amfgaiehgkg Smithman"
                }
            },
            "date": "2013-10-11T10:47:58.898Z"
        }
         }
     }
 });
```

and can **NOT** just call this:

```
Collection.update({"_id":"fTgR2YtHiZBzzqF6J"},
 {
    "$pull": {
        "following": {
             "user": {
                 "_id": "MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy"
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/17779687/149818. You query in general right and would be work just for case if you have exactly 1 `"user"`, but for multiple users you have to redesign your collection

Comment: Hey, thx for your input. I actually found that I have a different error, because I didn't get the concept in mongo ( which I think is bad. ) I will answer my own question as soon as I am allowed to. Basically: I can't just match for the user's _id but I have to match the whole object in the array containing {_id,fb{id,name}}

Comment: Just to find by such `_id` you need specify full path: `col.find({"following.user._id":"MAyxz4Yk5F9vh9RRy"})` - but note that `find` return record not the dictionary entry!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this answer ([Remove Item from Array in Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583305/remove-item-from-array-in-meteor-js)), I think it's a better fit, with less code.

Comment: thank you for looking over this. The only reason my code is so long, is that I wrote down an example so other users can understand the internals.

Comment: Gotcha, both a valid sources of information, they were equally good for me.